# gcloud triggers not working while deploying in firebase using composer in PHP

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, gcloud

I'm trying to run cloud function using triggers in firebase by PHP. But everytime I deploys in firebase, its showing composer issue.

I'm using latest version and enable the grpc also. But still its showing the error.

phpTest

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient;
use Google\CloudFunctions\CloudEvent;

function phpTest(CloudEvent $cloudevent)
{
    $data = $cloudevent->getData();
    $resource = $data['value']['name'];

    $db = new FirestoreClient();

    $docPath = explode('/documents/', $resource)[1];

    $affectedDoc = $db->document($docPath);

    $affectedDoc->set(['status' => 'checked']);
}
```

Composer

```
"require": {
        "google/cloud-functions-framework": "^1.0.0",
        "google/cloud-firestore": "1.25.0"
    }
```

I tried to run the above function using gcloud triggers by

```
gcloud functions deploy phpTest \
  --region asia-south1 \
  --runtime php82 \
  --trigger-resource "projects/test-dev/databases/(default)/documents/invoice/{docId}" \
  --trigger-event providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.write \
  --docker-registry=artifact-registry \
  --project test-dev
```

Its showing error in composer

`Problem 1 - google/cloud-firestore is locked to version v1.37.1 and an update of this package was not requested. - google/cloud-firestore v1.37.1 requires ext-grpc * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's grpc extension.; Error ID: 8fe845e7`